# Highcharts label behind the second series (but above the first series)

Tags: highcharts

I have 2 graphs on my chart.

One label related to  a specific dot in the second graph, and that label need to be placed at the **center** of that dot (**not** above/below/aside)

When we mouse over the red dots (in the second graph), a function is trigger.

### 3 problems:

1) this label **covers** the red middle dot. **I need it to be behind the red dot.**

2) For the same reson, (because of the label), that red dot **can't respond** to mouseOver / mouseOut/ click events.

3) I also want the label to be **above** the first graph(black line).

**I ilustarte that in this example:**  http://jsfiddle.net/yoav_barnea/YHwMf/

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',     
    height: 300
},
    tooltip:{
        enabled:false
    },

  //--------the series section:---------- 

 series: [
   //--- series 1:-----
 {
    data: [{x:4, y:15}, {x:12, y:7}, {x:25, y:27}],
    type:"spline",
    color:"black",
    zIndex:1
 },
   //--- series 2:-----
 {
   data: [  {x:3, y:3},

            {
               x:8,
               y:10,

               dataLabels:
                {  
                  enabled:true,
                  useHTML:true,
                  zIndex:4,
                  backgroundColor:"gray",
                  align:"center",
                  verticalAlign:"middle",
                  x:-20,
                  y:5,
                  color:"white",

                    formatter:function(){return "<b> vlaue:"+ this.y+"  <b/><br/>  my choice";}
               }
            }, // end of custom point




          {x:20, y:20}
         ]  ,   // end of points related to series 2   
       //--------------
     zIndex:10,
     type:"scatter",
     color:"red",
     point:{              
        events:{           
                 mouseOver: function (e) {
                    $("#message").text("you enter a red dot!").css("color","red");
                 } ,
             mouseOut: function (e) {
                    $("#message").text("please hover on the red dots").css("color","black");
                 }

        }            
      }   

 } // end of  series  2  


]   

}); // end of highcharts definitions

});// end of ready function
```

#### Also ,from highcharts documentation:

`The Z index of the data labels. The default Z index puts it above the series. Use a Z index of 2 to display it behind the series. Defaults to 6.`

I tried to play with the 'zIndex' property, but it doesn't seems to work. Is this a bug on their library, or am I missing somthing ?

### To summarize:

I need that label to be **above** the first graph(black line), **behind** the second graph(red dots), at the **center** of the middle red dot, and also that the **middle** red dot could respond to mouse events.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately dataLabels can be or under series, or above. You can't set different zIndex for different dataLabels, so to set zIndex use:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                zIndex: 1
            }
        }
    }
```

Second thing is about useHTML. When set to true, HTML tags are used in rendering labels, but HTML tags are always above SVG/VML, so zIndex won't work.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YHwMf/17/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. are you saying that labels can never be placed in the middle layer between 2 series. only beneath or above them both...?

Comment: Indeed, because in Highcharts structure all dataLabels are gouped in to one container, and the same for a series markers. So you can set higher or series, or dataLabels.